# [App registration][MS Graph] : permissions and URIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, app-permissions, sharepoint-app-registration

I am not familiar at all with the app registration under Azure AD, so this post might be a little erratic, and I am sorry for that. I will try to be as simplest and clearest as possible and ask you two questions about App registration under Azure Portal.

**Here is what a team need :**

They have an application (called Iterop) wich is basically a workflow application. This app will generate pdf documents.
It will need to push those documents under one precise folder in a Document Library under a SharePoint online Team site.

They can do it via calls to a REST API with the SharePoint endpoints.

I know you have to **register an app under Azure AD** to be able to generate a token (client's secret and all), so here are my questions about it :

1. Permissions

I read about permissions (those articles : [Granting access via Azure AD App-Only | Microsoft Docs][1] and [MS Graph Permissions References][2]) and they seem to be given Tenant-wide.

I only want this application to be able to communicate with **one team site**.
And inside this teamsite, i want it to **only read and possibly upload** documents in **one** document library.
I read a little article about a preview feature which is about [granting permission for selected site][3] but it seems to still be in preview, because I could not see it on the permission page with our Azure team.

So here is my question :
**What permission should the Azure team give the application to access only one Document Library in one specific team site and read/upload document in it ?**

2. URIs

My second question is about the URIs :

I don't fully understand their means, and I read (but can not find the documentation back) that you don't need to specify one if the API you are calling is for SharePoint.
**Could someone explain URIs to me please ?**

Thanks a lot, I hope you a wonderful day
[1]: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread
[2]: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#sites-permissions
[3]: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `POST sites/{site-id}/permissions` API to [create permission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for your application to access specific site with the permission
Sites.FullControl.All as the documentation mentioned. Hope this can help you.